# Auth0 connection to MySQL using OpenShift

Tags: mysql, connection, openshift, portforwarding, auth0

I'm using Auth0 to register users to my web app in Openshift which is using MySQL DB.

Auth0 reccomends:

**Heads up! If you are trying to access a service behind a firewall, make sure to open the right ports and allow inbound connections from these IP addresses: 138.91.154.99, 54.221.228.15, 54.183.64.135, 54.67.77.38, 54.67.15.170, 54.183.204.205, 54.173.21.107, 54.85.173.28**

But I am unable to forwards those ports and I can't connect the database to Auth0.

With the command:

```
$ rhc port-forward -a applicationName
```

I can only do it locally.

Thanks!